# Contact sync adapter in android

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I want to use sync adapter in my application to sync the native and third party contacts (except FB)  with server. ( Only client to server one way sync)

I have two doubts here -

1) If there are multiple sync adapters in the device and If dirty bit is already cleared by another sync adapter , would my sync adapter be able to detect the contacts change/update immediately.

2) I have used

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);
```

to sync the contacts with server .

It does start the sync in every 30 seconds .

But I want it to get notified immediately when ever contacts are added Or Deleted or Updated to start perfromSync operation.

Do I need to use observer too ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to see changes to the contacts you will have to register an observer with the ContentResolver. The sync API is not intended to watch for every change, it is intended to be a background API that Android runs periodically automatically for you, so that it can batch operations and use the network more efficiently, not run when network is disabled, etc...

The dirty bit is used on a per account basis. In general the sync is designed to have an "owning" account per contact, and is not designed for exporting all the contacts from the device to a particular service. There is an aggregation process that handles joining contacts from multiple accounts into one "Contact" as seen by the user. See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

For more information on how this works.

If you intend to export all contacts on the device to your service you will need to walk the contacts and insert a raw contact for your service. You will then also want to watch the ContentResolver with an observer to see when the user adds a new contact on some service or periodically walk the table looking for contacts you have not yet exported.

Answer (score 2):

use the **version bit**. If any contact edited
It automatically increased by 1.

so you create local database for compare previous **version** to current **version**. If any changes happen you trigger the update query.

for more information visit [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html).

This version helps for my sync updates. So I share this answer for all.